# job title normalizer

Tags: nlp, recommender-system, word2vec, bert

is there any way to normalize job titles using ml or nlp?

examples:

raw title:  UX/UI Engineers
normalized title:  Software Engineers

raw title:  UX/UI Designer
normalized title:  Graphic Designers

raw title:  .NET Developer
normalized title:  Web Developers

raw title:  Senior Android Engineer
normalized title:  Software Developers

raw title:  Jr ml engineer
normalized title:  ML Engineer

Comment: This kind of "fuzzy" task could be addressed with a large language model (LLM). You can use those examples in the instructions for the model to normalize a job title. You can read about such a technique [here](https://www.promptingguide.ai/techniques/fewshot).